# Reposition Old Unity GUI Buttons in Old Tutorial

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I've been trying to setup a team using the Photon Unity Network. My first of two questions is about the old GUI Buttons. Most answers point back to an old tut by quill18, in his FPS series,# 19 and 20. Problem is it's using the old GUI Buttons and he used some code to automatically place it in the center of the scene. This position hides the buttons in a background image.  I've tried replacing the Y value in the OnGui method to lower to the bottom third but nothing happens. How can I lower these buttons? This seems to be easier than trying to replace the old with the new GUI.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class NetworkManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject standbyCamera;
    SpawnSpot[] spawnSpots;

    public bool offlineMode = false;

    bool connecting = false;

    List<string> chatMessages;
    int maxChatMessages = 5;

    public float respawnTimer = 0;

    bool hasPickedTeam = false;
    int teamID=0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        spawnSpots = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<SpawnSpot>();
        PhotonNetwork.player.name = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Username", "Awesome Dude");
        chatMessages = new List<string>();
    }

    void OnDestroy() {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Username", PhotonNetwork.player.name);
    }

    public void AddChatMessage(string m) {
        GetComponent<PhotonView>().RPC ("AddChatMessage_RPC", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered, m);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    void AddChatMessage_RPC(string m) {
        while(chatMessages.Count >= maxChatMessages) {
            chatMessages.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        chatMessages.Add(m);
    }

    void Connect() {
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings( "MultiFPS v004" );
    }

    void OnGUI() {
        GUILayout.Label( PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString() );

        if(PhotonNetwork.connected == false && connecting == false ) {
            // We have not yet connected, so ask the player for online vs offline mode.
            GUILayout.BeginArea( new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height) );
            GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
            GUILayout.BeginVertical();
            GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();

            GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            GUILayout.Label("Username: ");
            PhotonNetwork.player.name = GUILayout.TextField(PhotonNetwork.player.name);
            GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

            if( GUILayout.Button("Single Player") ) {
                connecting = true;
                PhotonNetwork.offlineMode = true;
                OnJoinedLobby();
            }

            if( GUILayout.Button("Multi Player") ) {
                connecting = true;
                Connect ();
            }

            GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
            GUILayout.EndVertical();
            GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
            GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            GUILayout.EndArea();
        }

        if(PhotonNetwork.connected == true && connecting == false) {

            if(hasPickedTeam) {
                // We are fully connected, make sure to display the chat box.
                GUILayout.BeginArea( new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height) );
                GUILayout.BeginVertical();
                GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();

                foreach(string msg in chatMessages) {
                    GUILayout.Label(msg);
                }

                GUILayout.EndVertical();
                GUILayout.EndArea();
            }
            else {
                // Player has not yet selected a team.

                GUILayout.BeginArea( new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height) );
                GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
                GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
                GUILayout.BeginVertical();
                GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();

                if( GUILayout.Button("Red Team") ) {
                    SpawnMyPlayer(1);
                }

                if( GUILayout.Button("Green Team") ) {
                    SpawnMyPlayer(2);
                }

                if( GUILayout.Button("Random") ) {
                    SpawnMyPlayer(Random.Range(1,3));   // 1 or 2
                }

                if( GUILayout.Button("Renegade!") ) {
                    SpawnMyPlayer(0);
                }

                GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
                GUILayout.EndVertical();
                GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
                GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
                GUILayout.EndArea();


            }

        }

    }

    void OnJoinedLobby() {
        Debug.Log ("OnJoinedLobby");
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
    }

    void OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed() {
        Debug.Log ("OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed");
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom( null );
    }

    void OnJoinedRoom() {
        Debug.Log ("OnJoinedRoom");

        connecting = false;
        //SpawnMyPlayer();
    }

    void SpawnMyPlayer(int teamID) {
        this.teamID = teamID;
        hasPickedTeam = true;
        AddChatMessage("Spawning player: " + PhotonNetwork.player.name);

        if(spawnSpots == null) {
            Debug.LogError ("WTF?!?!?");
            return;
        }

        SpawnSpot mySpawnSpot = spawnSpots[ Random.Range (0, spawnSpots.Length) ];
        GameObject myPlayerGO = (GameObject)PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("PlayerController", mySpawnSpot.transform.position, mySpawnSpot.transform.rotation, 0);
        standbyCamera.SetActive(false);

        //((MonoBehaviour)myPlayerGO.GetComponent("FPSInputController")).enabled = true;
        ((MonoBehaviour)myPlayerGO.GetComponent("MouseLook")).enabled = true;
        ((MonoBehaviour)myPlayerGO.GetComponent("PlayerMovement")).enabled = true;
        ((MonoBehaviour)myPlayerGO.GetComponent("PlayerShooting")).enabled = true;

        myPlayerGO.GetComponent<TeamMember>().teamID = teamID;
        SkinnedMeshRenderer mySkin = myPlayerGO.transform.GetComponentInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();

        if(mySkin == null) {
            Debug.LogError("Couldn't find a SkinnedMeshRenderer!");
        }

        if(teamID==1)
            mySkin.material.color = Color.red;
        if(teamID==2)
            mySkin.material.color = new Color(.5f, 1f, .5f);

        myPlayerGO.transform.FindChild("Main Camera").gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    void Update() {
        if(respawnTimer > 0) {
            respawnTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

            if(respawnTimer <= 0) {
                // Time to respawn the player!
                SpawnMyPlayer(teamID);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advice updating to the new UI indeed.

try to insert a GUILayout.Space next to the flexible space https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayout.Space.html

This usually helps a lot to move things in flexible content layouts.